Inverted latitude axis only for mosaic image in GeoServer
I have a dataset that I want to serve in GeoServer as an image mosaic. Currently, everything works fine except that the data have the latitude inverted. Here is the link to the preview of that said layer.
For the sake of testing, I currently only have one tif file in the directory and the database for the indexes is not yet set. But the time dimension is not enable yet on it so it shouldnt be the cause of the problem?
To try finding the problem, I have also created another layer (GeoTIFF store) with the same GeoTIFF file as the one in the image mosaic. And the style of the layer is the same as well. And this layer is actually not flipped like the image mosaic. Here is the Geo layer.
Am I missing a parameter in the creation of the image mosaic that could be responsible for the inversion of the y axis?

You need to let us know exactly which SRS you have used and what  gdalinfo  shows for your image - review https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/services/wfs/axis_order.html#axis-ordering for more details of what might be happening

The relevant part of the gdalinfo is this one:
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -72.6000000,  46.0000000)
Lower Left  ( -72.6000000,  49.5000000)
Upper Right ( -68.0000000,  46.0000000)
Lower Right ( -68.0000000,  49.5000000)
The y axis indeed looks like it was inverted. I thus flipped the data and adjusted the transform parameter when creating the GeoTIFF. And everything turned out to be good!
What I dont understand is why was it fine for the GeoTIFF store, and not the image mosaic? Is the layer processing different ?

probably because 4326 doesn't always mean lat. lon depending on the context

Performing gdalinfo on the file showed the latitude axis was actually inverted.  Flipping the data and adjusting the transform parameter when creating the GeoTIFF corrected the behavior.
